# Enzyme mount wrapper's containsAllMatchingElements fails to find elements

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test whether a `Menu` renders it's `MenuItems`:

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import { mount } from "enzyme";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const MenuItem = ({ children }) => <li>{children}</li>;
const Menu = () => (
  <ul>
    <MenuItem>foo</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>bar</MenuItem>
  </ul>
);

const HyperMenu = () => <Menu />;

const wrapper = mount(<HyperMenu />);

expect(wrapper.containsAllMatchingElements([<MenuItem />])).toBeTruthy();
```

though it looks like [a valid case](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/containsAllMatchingElements.html), enzyme cannot find any `MenuItems` and the test fails. Why is that?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/18w4o3q713)

`wrapper.debug()` spits

```jsx
<HyperMenu>
  <Menu>
    <ul>
      <MenuItem>
        <li>
          foo
        </li>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        <li>
          bar
        </li>
      </MenuItem>
    </ul>
  </Menu>
</HyperMenu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`containsAllMatchingElements` works by determining "if an element in the wrapper looks like" the elements passed "by checking if all props of the expected element" are present.

One of the "Common Gotchas" listed at the bottom of the docs is to "keep in mind that this method determines matching based on the matching of the node's children as well".

Looking at the source code, the comparison is done by the function [`internalNodeCompare`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme/src/Utils.js#L115) which compares the props [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme/src/Utils.js#L127-L142) and the children [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme/src/Utils.js#L144-L155).

In the test above `containsAllMatchingElements` is passed `<MenuItem />` which causes it to look for a `MenuItem` with no props and no children which fails because the two `MenuItem` elements in the wrapper both have children.

The test passes if it is modified to include the `MenuItem` children:

```jsx
expect(wrapper.containsAllMatchingElements([<MenuItem>foo</MenuItem>, <MenuItem>bar</MenuItem>])).toBeTruthy();   // SUCCESS
```